# Installer for ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, installation

I have an ASP.NET project in VS2012. I'd like to publish an "offline" version of this site.

I'd like the installer, to:

- Enable (or install) the IIS on Windows (if necessary)
- Install the MS SQLExpress (if necessary)
- Install the .NET (if necessary)
- Install the project's files, and start the site on localhost.

Can you help me, how to start?

Comment: Consider using Katana & SQL CE so you can be standalone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSI packages (digitally signed) are the standard way of deploying Windows applications. You can use a tool like Advanced Installer, such tools offer predefined support to [install Windows Features](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/windows-features.html), [prerequisites (SQLExpress or .NET Framework)](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/prerequisites.html), [install IIS web apps](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-iis.html) and of course [copy your files and create the corresponding folders structure](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html#files).

This application has a free edition, but for what you need you have to purchase a Pro license. It also has a [full 30 days trial](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html).
(disclaimer: I work on it)

Answer (score 0):

If not going with @SLaks suggestion, you have to create either a script (powershell) or a installation package to setup all the components in your solution. There a a bunch of installation packages around ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software)